# Calculating Execution time and big O time of my c++ program

Tags: c++, big-o, execution-time

My Code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
//#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>
//using namespace std;
inline int overlap(std::pair<int,int> classes[],int size)
{
  std::sort(classes,classes+size);
  int count=0,count1=0,count2=0;
  int tempi,tempk=1;
  for(unsigned int i=0;i<(size-1);++i)
  {
      tempi = classes[i].second;
      for(register unsigned int j=i+1;j<size;++j)
      {
          if(!(classes[i].first<classes[j].second && classes[i].second>classes[j].first))
          {   if(count1 ==1)
              {
                  count2++;
              }
              if(classes[i].second == tempi)
              {
                  tempk =j;
                  count1 = 1;
              }
              ////cout<<"\n"<<"Non-Overlapping Class:\t";
              ////cout<<classes[i].first<<"\t"<<classes[i].second<<"\t"<<classes[j].first<<"\t"<<classes[j].second<<"\n";
              classes[i].second = classes[j].second;
              count++;
              if(count1==1 && j ==(size-1))
              {
                 j= tempk;
                 classes[i].second = tempi;
                 count1= 0;
                 if(count2 !=0)
                 {
                    count = (count + ((count2)-1));
                 }
                 count2 =0;
              }
          } 
          else
          {
              if(j ==(size-1))
              {
                 if(count>0)
                 {
                 j= tempk;
                 classes[i].second = tempi;
                 count1= 0;
                 if(count2 !=0)
                 {
                  count = (count + ((count2)-1));
                 }
                 count2 =0;
                 }
              }
          }
      }
  }
  count = count + size;
  return count;
}
inline int fastRead_int(int &x) {
    register int c = getchar_unlocked();
    x = 0;
    int neg = 0;
    for(; ((c<48 || c>57) && c != '-'); c = getchar_unlocked());
    if(c=='-') {
        neg = 1;
        c = getchar_unlocked();
    }
    for(; c>47 && c<58 ; c = getchar_unlocked()) {

        x = (x<<1) + (x<<3) + c - 48;
    }
    if(neg)

        x = -x;
 return x;
}
int main()
{
   int N;
   ////cout<<"Please Enter Number Of Classes:";
   clock_t begin,end;
   float time_interval;
   begin = clock();
   while(fastRead_int(N))
   {
   switch(N)
   {
    case -1 : end = clock();
              time_interval = float(end - begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
              printf("Execution Time = %f",time_interval);
              return 0;
    default : 
     unsigned int subsets;
     unsigned int  No = N;
     std::pair<int,int> classes[N];
     while(No--)
     {
       ////cout<<"Please Enter Class"<<(i+1)<<"Start Time and End Time:";
       int S, E;
       fastRead_int(S);
       fastRead_int(E);
       classes[N-(No+1)] = std::make_pair(S,E);
     }
     subsets = overlap(classes,N);
     ////cout<<"\n"<<"Total Number Of Non-Overlapping Classes is:";
     printf("%08d",subsets);
     printf("\n");
     break;
   }
   }
}
```

and Input and output of my program:

```
Input:
5
1 3
3 5
5 7
2 4
4 6
3
500000000 1000000000
1 5
1 5
1 
999999999 1000000000
-1

Output:
Success time: 0 memory: 3148 signal:0
00000012
00000005
00000001
Execution Time = 0.000036
```

I tried to calculate by having clocks at start of main and end of main and found out the time.But it said only some 0.000036 secs.But when I tried to post the same code in Online Judge(SPOJ).My program got 'Time Limit Exceeded' Error. Time Limit for the above program in SPOJ is 2.365 secs.Could somebody help me figure out this?

Comment: You can not calculate big(O) with timestamps. Those are strictly dependent in one's setup. What if you had an algorithm that by average it takes 30secs and when you run it in a super computer you get the result instantly. Would this be accurate?

Comment: maybe the hidden test cases of SPOJ are too big..you should optimize more your code.

Comment: Big O and perfomance are two separate things. Big O is an classification of your algorithm depending on how many significant operations your perform. Performance is how you program fares on a specific configuration.

Comment: _"Could somebody help me figure out this?"_ That's very vague. Have you tried asking a friend or mentor to step you through it? I don't see how this question will be useful in the future.

Comment: It would be nice if you let us know which problem you are trying to solve!

Comment: You use `(x<<1) + (x<<3)` for `x*10`... maybe you should let this to the compiler.

Comment: HI Tony...I tried to solve SPOJ activ program...URL is as follows:http://www.spoj.com/problems/ACTIV/.

Comment: Hi Orace...ya I use that for x* 10 for better performance.is it not the right way to acheive it?

Answer (score 0):

I consider that your question is about the `overlap` function.

In it, you have

- A sort call: O(n×ln(n))
- two `for` loops:

  - the first is roughly `0..Size`
  - the second (nested in the first) is roughly `i..Size`

The *inside* of the second loop is called Size(Size+1) / 2 (reverse sum of the N first integer) times with no breaks.

So your algorithm is O(n²) where n is the size.

Comment: Hi Orace...thanks for your answer...I know O(n^2) is the worst case in time complexity. Is there a way to acheive  O(nlogn) (or for better performance) for the same code without affecting the functionality?

Comment: I tried my best in optimizing the above code. Used getchar_unlimited() instead of cin. and used register variable for inner loops. Used While loop for getting inputs instead of for loop. Anything more can I do to improve the performance of the code?

Comment: Those are local optimization, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization. As I say, compiler will probably do a better work than you. You will just divide the time by a constant. And O(n²/k) is O(n²). That is not what you are looking for. You have to change you algorithm design to reach O(n×ln(n)) (if it's possible). Also, please explain what your algorithm do if you want any help about it.

Comment: SPOJ ACTIV - http://www.spoj.com/problems/ACTIV/ is the question am trying to solve. I sorted time intervals then tried to compare the first time interval with the next to check if it is overlapping or not.if they are not overlapping, I merged those two intervals and check with the next.Likewise till the last time interval am proceeding. once reaches the last, I continue the same process from second interval to last and then third interval to last and go on.